# Get PAGE_SHIFT value in user space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

When in linux kernel space one can always use the kernel's own PAGE_SIZE and PAGE_SHIFT macros, but when I want to write user space code that will work regardless from the size of the size of these variables in the current machine, I have to use sysconf. For example to get the size of a page one could run sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE). However I am looking for the PAGE_SHIFT value. Is there a similar proper way to get it or do I have to calculate it from the size of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PAGE_SHIFT` should be in `<sys/user.h>`

```bash
$ printf '#include <sys/user.h>\nPAGE_SHIFT' | gcc -xc -E -P - | tail -n1
12
```

Comment: So if i include sys/user.h in my C code I will be able to use the macro PAGE_SHIFT in my code?

Comment: I tried it and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a fixed PAGE_SHIFT because the page size is not necessarily a constant on all architectures.

You can use the first bit set (should be only bit set as the page size is always a power of 2!) to determine the shift.  There are numerous coding examples of this on-line.  (Some libraries probably have a ffs or bsf or similar function to do this.)

Comment: I didn't want to use a fixed PAGE_SHIFT. I wanted exactly the opposite. I was looking for a way to get the PAGE_SHIFT value from the system so that I can run the program irregardless of the current architecture. And the answer was indeed to include sys/user.h